# Can not run an OpenVino model using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cmake, neural-network, openvino

I have built OpenCV with OpenVino. And I have code which has to run an OpenVino model:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace dnn;

void TestOpenVinoModel()
{   
    // Another model
    string mapping_path = "C:\\ROOT1\\opencv_build_test\\files_openvino_2\\ssdlite_mobilenet_v2.mapping";
    string xml_path = "C:\\ROOT1\\opencv_build_test\\files_openvino_2\\ssdlite_mobilenet_v2.xml";
    string bin_path = "C:\\ROOT1\\opencv_build_test\\files_openvino_2\\ssdlite_mobilenet_v2.bin";

    Net openvino_model = readNetFromModelOptimizer(xml_path, bin_path);
    openvino_model.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CPU);
    Mat img = imread("C:\\ROOT1\\opencv_build_test\\car_300x300.jpg");
    Mat blob = blobFromImage(img, 0.007843f, Size(300, 300), Scalar(127.5f, 127.5f, 127.5f), false);

    openvino_model.setInput(blob);
    Mat detections = openvino_model.forward();
    Mat detections_reshaped = detections.reshape(1, detections.total() / 7);

    for (int i = 0; i < detections_reshaped.rows; ++i) {
        float confidence = detections_reshaped.at<float>(i, 2);
        if (confidence > 0.5) {
            int x_left = static_cast<int>(detections_reshaped.at<float>(i, 3) * img.cols);
            int y_top = static_cast<int>(detections_reshaped.at<float>(i, 4) * img.rows);
            int x_right = static_cast<int>(detections_reshaped.at<float>(i, 5) * img.cols);
            int y_bottom = static_cast<int>(detections_reshaped.at<float>(i, 6) * img.rows);

            rectangle(img, Point(x_left, y_top), Point(x_right, y_bottom), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        }
    }

    imshow("Image", img);
    waitKey();
}

int main()
{
    TestOpenVinoModel();

    return 0;
}
```

But it crashes after the string

```
Mat detections = openvino_model.forward();
```

on

```
void CNNNetwork::reshape(const std::map<std::string, std::vector<size_t> >& shapes) ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnRgh.png)

Can anybody help me?

I have built OpenCV with the following flags:

```
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_OPENVINO=ON -DBUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF -DOPENCV_DNN_OPENVINO=ON -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=OFF
```

Maybe I built incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenVINO's latest release (2022.3 or 2022.1) version, OpenCV is not included with the installation package. Below are the steps to build OpenCV.

1. Download and install [OpenVINO version of 2022.3 or 2022.1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html).
2. Download OpenCV from [opencv/opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) repository.

   git clone --recurse-submodules -b 4.5.5-openvino-2022.1.0 https://github/opencv/opencv.git
3. Setup environment variables to detect Inference Engine.

   <INSTALL_DIR>\setupvars.bat
4. Create build directory and navigate to build directory.

   cd opencv

   mkdir build && cd build
5. Compile and install OpenCV with minimal set of compilation flags.

   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_OPENVINO=ON ..

Additional information, In OpenVINO 2021.4 version, OpenCV is included.